# String.getBytes() faster than charset.encode

Tags: java, arrays, string, encoding, character-encoding

When to use String.getBytes("") and Charset.enocde(String) ?

a) usage of string getbytes
return "testingtestingtestingtesting".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

b) usage of charset encode
Charset charset = Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
return charset.encode("testingtestingtestingtestingtesting").array()

Quick testing suggests str.getbytes is much faster than charset.encode.

1. Why str.getbytes is faster than charset.encode
2. What are the factors that should decide chosing between these 2 options ?

result of testing:  getBytes() method takes 1328 ms while charset.encode() takes 1804 ms

[result of testing with sample program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JvzA.png)

Comment: Can you post the *quick testing*?

Comment: @GeorgeZ. pasted the image link with result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The charset `UTF_8` using `ArrayEncoder` and `getBytes()` has fast path for it.
2. `Charset.encode` always wraps the parameter as a `CharBuffer` and return a `ByteBuffer` instead of `byte[]`, and it is using encoder cache. `String.getBytes` always create a new `CharsetEncoder` and using `char[]` for encoding, and it has fast path for `ArrayEncoder`.

Additionally, the `ArrayEncoder` is also a fast path encoder for `char[]` to `byte[]` encoding.

However, this performance should not be considered in most applications.

Comment: are you saying that performance difference between these 2 usages is negligible ?

Comment: @M.Shashanka In most applications, yes. Why do we need to encode String as a byte array? Because we need to do some I/O or crypto. There is much slower than string encoding. Therefore, we don't need consider about this in most applications.